# Understanding a proof of uncountably of $\mathbb{R}$ using decimal expansions

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand this proof that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

> Proceeding by contradiction, suppose there exists a surjection $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$. Consider the possible decimal expansions of $f(n)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$; there may be multiple. Consider the $n$th place after the decimal point, and let $S_n$ be the set of integers that appear in this $n$th place among the possible decimal expansions. Having fixed an $n$, $S_n$ has at most two elements. Now, for each $n$, pick $a_n$ satisfying $0 \leq a_n \leq 9$, an integer not in $S_n$. We can do that as $|S_n| \leq 2$. Now consider $A = 0.a_1 a_2 a_3 \ldots$ Then $a \neq f(n)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ as it differs from $f(n)$ in the $n$th decimal place, so $a \not \in \mathrm{Im}(f)$. So $f$ is not a surjection.

There are two things I don't fully understand.

(1) How do we know there are only two possible digits in the $n$th decimal place? I cannot figure out how to prove this, but I know "intuitively" that there's can be an expansion ending in an string of $9$'s and an expansion ending in a string of $0$'s.

(2) This proof does not consider binary expansions, so why am I only required to consider the digits after the decimal point? Is it enough to simply differ in these positions to ensure $a \not \in f(\mathbb{N})$?

UPDATE: Proposed proof of (1):

> In fact, every real number has at most two decimal expansions. There are three exhaustive possibilities. First, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ terminates, then decrementing the last digit and appending an infinite string of $9$'s gives an alternate decimal expansion of $x$. Second, if the decimal expansion of $x$ ends with an infinite string of $9$'s, then we can find another decimal expansion by the deleting the sequence of $9$s and incrementing the final digit. Third and finally, if the decimal expansion of $x$ fails to terminate without an infinite string of $9$s, it has only a single, unique decimal expansion.

Comment: An expansion that ends in a string of 9's or 0's has either a 9 or a 0 in the gazillionth place. So if you change the gazillionth digit to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, or 8, you have a different number.

Comment: Given any position $S_n$, the maximum value of the digits after the $n$th place is $10^{-n}$ and the minimum value is $0$. Thus, if two digits that are at least $2$ apart form valid representations, then the digits after the $n$th place have to sum to $2\cdot10^{-n}$, a contradiction. This shows $(1)$.

Comment: If you can prove that the digits after the decimal point are different, then you don't need to care about numbers before the decimal point; they can only make the numbers more different.

Comment: @gnasher729 Your justification for $(1)$ is not valid (or at least far too handwavy to be called justification).

Comment: I am not sure I understand your point (2). A similar proof using binary expansions can be given but the bit of the argument that depends on the fact that are at least $3$ possible digits needs to be modified.  The focus on digits after the decimal point is just simplicity.

Comment: @DonThousand I added an updated proof of (1). Does this look correct / fully rigorous?

Answer (score 1):

1. Most real numbers have one and only one decimal expansion. Those which have more than one have exactly two decimal expansions. These are the real numbers that can be written as $\pm\frac a{10^b}$ for a natural number $a$ and a non-negative integer $b$. Suppose, say, that $a=123$ and that $b=1$. Then$$\frac a{10^b}=1.23=1.229999999999\ldots$$
2. The analysis of what happens with the digits after the decimal point is enough to prove what we want to prove. So, there is no need to bother with the remaining digits.